# Removing duplicate value from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have created angularjs app in which I have made quiz module in which question 1-5 has same description then question 6-7 has same description so I have save same description to each question and display them using one by one on next button. now the functionality is change I want to display on single page so I have used ng-repeat now the problem is the question description is also repeating so same description is showing for every 1-5 questions my JSON is like

```
[ { 
  description:'xxxxxx',
  question:'abcd',
  correctAnswer:'A',
  hasSameDesc:true
},
{ 
  description:'xxxxxx',
  question:'pqr',
  correctAnswer:'B'
  hasSameDesc:true
},
{ 
  description:'xxxxxx',
  question:'XYZQ',
  correctAnswer:'A'
  hasSameDesc:true
}] and so on
```

Now I want to display that description once on above the first question and remains question from 2-5 remains without description
so anyone have suggestion how do I do this?
thanx in advanced.

Comment: `my json is like` - if that is JSON, it's invalid

Comment: Show us the HTML code you have, more specifically the `ng-repeat` you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I'd rename your JSON object properties "question1", "question2", etc.. to "question", otherwise you're essentially iterating over an array of different objects, which just makes things harder.

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions track by $index">
  <h1 ng-if="$index == 0 || $index == 5"> {{question.description}} </h1>
  <span>{{question.question}}</span>
</div>
```

Is this close to what you mean? Basically with an `ng-repeat` you can choose which properties of the objects you're iterating over you want to show.

Comment: my scenario is like 1-5 has same description then 6-7 has same description so from {{questions[0].description}} is showing first description only

Comment: @kalpeshR I've updated my answer, the description will only be shown for the 1st and 6th question

Comment: I have just given example there are some question that have no description like 1st question has no description then after 2-4 has description then 5-6 has no description then again 7 has description then ?the order of description is not fix it can be any where

Comment: @kalpeshR You just said "1-5 has the same description, 6-7 also has the same description" and now you're saying that question 1, 5 and 6 have no description? Which is it? Show us the full JSON and HTML code you have

Comment: @ Robin-Hoodie I just want to say that the same description can be anywhere in JSON like there are 20 questions in which 1st question has no description and 2-6 has same description then after 7-8 has same description then 8-9 has no description like that

Comment: @kalpeshR Okay, and do you want to only show one question of the ones who have the same description? Or do you want to show all the questions but not repeat duplicate descriptions?

Comment: yes ,I wan to show all questions  but not repeat duplicate descriptions

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to filter array before display it.

It this example first appropriate value takes. You can modify conditions to find totally or partially uniq objects

```js
let data = [ { 
  description:'xxxxxx',
  question1:'abcd',
  correctAnswer:'A',
  hasSameDesc:true
},
{ 
  description:'xxxxxx',
  question2:'pqr',
  correctAnswer:'B',
  hasSameDesc:true
},
{ 
  description:'xxxxxx',
  question3:'XYZQ',
  correctAnswer:'A',
  hasSameDesc:true
},
{ 
  description:'yyyyy',
  question3:'XYZQ',
  correctAnswer:'A',
  hasSameDesc:true
}];

let uniq = data.filter((elem, index, self) => {
  return index == self.findIndex(e => elem.description == e.description)
})

console.log(uniq)
```

Comment: thanx for the answer but this removing other question I want all question except duplicate description

Comment: Could you print an example of input data and expected output?